# Story about a young woman expelled from a military academy

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely recall reading an SF story about a young woman expelled from a space navy academy for what seemed a poor reason. She got assigned to a civilian ship due to family connections (perhaps they owned it?).

She ends up becoming leader of armed ships (armed merchanters?). They fight a pirate fleet and discover there is a conspiracy to overthrow her home world.

A female relative (an aunt?) seems to be a retired spy and also gets involved.

I THOUGHT this was the Elizabeth Moon series about Heris Serrano ... but that ain't it.

Comment: Huh, I just read the title and immediately thought of Elizabeth Moon - Never read this story though, only the Paksenarrion series (which is amazing). That series does contain a similar theme, so the connection is not super far-fetched...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Elizabeth Moon, but it's the [*Vatta's War*](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/m/elizabeth-moon/vattas-war/) series. She thought she was helping a fellow student to get access to a priest of their religion, but the student was some sort of spy. There's 5 books in the series, and a linked duology called *Vatta's Peace*.

Comment: wheeee! [*grin*] that is it ... and for some reason i have lost my paperbacks of the books. time to go a-hunting at half-price books ... [*grin*]